# Setting background image or image to uibutton in ios7 causes memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, ios7, uibutton

I tried to set image for `UIButton` when it run on iOS 7 produces leaks in iOS libraries like imageIO CGImageRef etc. But When I tried with iOS 6 simulator it works fine no leaks.

Comment: Do you have the problem on a device with iOS 7 or the iOS 7 simulator?

Comment: I tried with simulator only. with instruments

Comment: It's common for the simulator to have leaks that don't exist in real devices. Test on a real device. If there is no leak then ignore the problem in the simulator.